# how to automatically fetch api data using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, fetch, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to fetch data from "/api/auth/profile" which responds with a user data taken from token. Through this, if token exists, user can do some functions which requires authorization. In order to know if the user authorizated or not, I need to fetch that data first automatically when user visit's the website. How can I fetch it in redux toolkit so that I can use it in many pages. Here's the code I tried

```
import { createSlice,createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchUserInfo = createAsyncThunk("fetchUserInfo", async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/profile")
  return res.json()
})

const userInfo = createSlice({
  name:"userInfo",
  initialState:{
    data:null
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserInfo.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    })
  }
})

export default userInfo.reducer;
```

I used RTK query version as well,but it didn't work since Redux store provider and Api provider gets conflict when they're used together.

Even I tried using setTimeOut:

```
import { fetchUserInfo } from '../../redux/userSlice';

 setTimeout(()=>{
    dispatch(fetchUserInfo())
    console.log("implemented")
  },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

as for me, I put similar requests in some root element like `<App>` and set polling

Comment: there's the second part of the question then, why I'm getting error response here when fetching through redux toolkit, and success response when fetching with .js file? what can be the reason for this